# Filtering one table using multiple inputs

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**The schema**

Date table with the standard fields such as date, week number etc.

Data table with the relevant fields being id no, created date and closed date.

**The set-up**
[image]

I have two measures for calculating the number of tasks opened each week:

```
 Created on Date = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Data table'[number]),
                   USERELATIONSHIP('Data table'[Created Date],'Date'[Date])) + 0
 Closed on Date = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Data table'[number]),
                   USERELATIONSHIP('Data table'[Closed Date],'Date'[Date])) + 0
```

Each number is shown on the relevant column chart.

**The task**

In the table below the column charts, I would like to list ONLY the tasks related to a selected column from any table.  So for example if week 41 is selected from the "Created" table, I would like to see only the relevant eight record which were created that week without any which happened to be closed on that week.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Can you supply a .pbix?

Comment: As @David stated well below, why you needed that + 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 week-number columns based on `'Data table'[Created Date]` and `'Data table'[Closed Date]`.

```
Created week number = WEEKNUM('Data table'[Created Date])
Closed week number = WEEKNUM('Data table'[Closed Date])
```

And then set `Created week number` to X-axis of the first column chart, `Closed week number` to X-axis of the second column chart.

So if week 41 is selected from the `"Created"` column chart, we can see only the relevant eight records which were created that week.
[image]

And if week 41 is selected from the `"Closed"` column chart, we can see only the relevant one record which were created that week.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, wanted to avoid using calculated columns but seems that without making major changes to the report it's the best way to go forward.